# Does the Pirate Browser circumvent corporate website filters?

Tags: browser, web-filtering

Hypothetically speaking, of course, if SWIM installed the Pirate Browser on their work computer which has certain filers installed which block certain website such as facebook for example, would this browser be able to circumvent this filtering?

I realise that installing an application without permission is forbidden and I understand all the legal and ethical concerns involved. I'm simply curious.

Comment: Pirate Browser seems to be a GPL violation.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on where the filtering is taking place.  However, filtering of websites is rarely done at the browser level.  Usually its done at the network level and using a different browser will not bypass the filters.

Comment: Grand. That was what I thought, but I wasn't sure exactly how the pirate browser worked so I was curious. Thanks!